# How can I replace the code inside my master with another branch

Tags: git

I have a project at work in which I worked on different branches for features and for different reasons the current branch that should be deployed is too different from master. I think merging it will be problematic. Should I rebase? What is the actual way to replace the master branches contents with another branch?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a branch point to a particular revision?

Comment: If you want `master` to refer to a different commit, just change it.  `git update-ref refs/heads/master other-branch`

Comment: As an educational sidenote / as context for why this is simple, do note that branches "don't exist" in git. Branches are just pointers to commits. They can be moved around arbitrarily, and if you delete one, there's essentially no record that it ever existed. It's only the commits that actually carry information. If you _really_ wanted to, it's perfectly possible to use git without any branches.